# Badges icons are displayed per current SE website, not per SE website you earned that badge in

Tags: bug, badges

In my "Achievements" panel I can see that I have earned a badge for a question in StackOverflow. However if I'm in another website from the StackExchange Network the badge changes its icon according to the website I'm visiting. Screenshot applied - I'm in Travel.SE.
[image]

Is it by design? :)